# Search input in AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an activity that extends of AppCompatActivity, and requires the search function.

I've got that the magnifying glass icon appears at the right of the Action Bar, but the search's "text view" doesn't appear when I click on the icon.

The search_menu.xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

And the Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu code is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The class declaration is:

`public class NasActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the support searchview:

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Comment: Perfect! This works successfully. Thank you very much, Andre!